# TSQL substring of variable length

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

With the following string samples, how can I extract "Acceleration", "Speeding", "Braking"?

```
@String = 'Alarm Time: 28/08/2014 08:45:50  Alarm Status: Acceleration, Accepted by joe.bloggs' 
@String = 'Alarm Time: 28/08/2014 08:47:25  Alarm Status: Speeding, Accepted by jane.doe'
@String = 'Alarm Time: 28/08/2014 08:50:14  Alarm Status: Braking, Accepted by john.doe'
```

As you can see an Alarm Status can be of variable length.

I'm assuming I need a combination of `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX` and possible `LEFT` functions but I'm getting completely lost.

For example, this works for getting the Alarm Time but only because the Alarm Time is of fixed length.

```
RIGHT(SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX('Alarm Time: ', @String),31),19)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: CharIndex optionally takes a second parameter telling it which character to start searching from. You could search for `,`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want everything after `Alarm status:` then this should work:

```
select substring(@String, charindex('Status: ', @string, 0)+8, len(@string))
```

If you only want the keyword ("Acceleration", "Speeding", "Braking"):

```
select substring(@String, charindex('Status: ', @string, 0)+8, charindex(',',substring(@String, charindex('Status: ', @string, 0)+8, len(@string)),0)-1)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21291) for both versions above

Edit: a shorter version for just the keywords ([fiddle for this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21292))

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(
    @String,    -- string to be searched
    (CHARINDEX('s:', @String) + 2), -- start position
    CHARINDEX(',', @String) - (CHARINDEX('s:', @String) + 2) -- length 
    )
```

Comment: "how can I extract "Acceleration", "Speeding", "Braking"?" is pretty clear that he doesn't want the stuff after it.

Comment: Thank you jpw, an alternative to my untidy attempt.

Comment: @Mountaineer I added a short version at the end that should work too.

Answer (score 0):

My very ugly solution:

```
declare @String as varchar(100) = 'Alarm Time: 28/08/2014 08:45:50  Alarm Status:   Acceleration, Accepted by joe.bloggs' 

select @string
,
ltrim(rtrim(
replace
(
replace
(
substring
(
substring(@string, patindex('%Alarm Status:%,%', @string), len(@string))
,1
,patindex('%,%', substring(@string, patindex('%Alarm Status:%,%', @string),    len(@string))))
, 'Alarm Status:', ''), ',', '')))
```

I am not checking for case where string does not contain the string [Alarm Status].  This could be added.

Solution 2 with some assumptions made: You are always looking for either 'Acceleration', 'Speeding' or 'Braking'; the words occur only once per string exclusively - if a string has 'Acceleration' it is not going to have 'Speeding' or 'Braking'; 
In this case you can use something like:

```
declare @String as varchar(100) 
set @String = 'Alarm Time: 28/08/2014 08:45:50  Alarm Status: Acceleration, Accepted by joe.bloggs' 

select case 
    when charindex('Acceleration', @string) > 0 then 'Acceleration'
    when charindex('Speeding', @string) > 0 then 'Speeding'
    when charindex('Braking', @string) > 0 then 'Braking'
    else null
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with this not so tidy solution.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, ( CHARINDEX('Alarm Status: ', @String) + LEN('Alarm Status: ') ), CHARINDEX(', Accepted by ', @String) - (CHARINDEX('Alarm Status: ', @String) + LEN('Alarm Status: ')))
```

Any improvements on it would be appreciated.